# Is there an R function that can identify sequences with random letters in it as unique?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to identify different letter-sequences and recode them.

Let me explain with an example:
The sequence "ABABA" has 2 unique letters "A" and "B". I want to recode this sequence with a "2".
The second sequence "BABAB" also has 2 unique letters "A" and "B", therefore this sequence should be recoded with "2" aswell.

It gets difficult once you have more different letters, because you can get thousands of combinations, f.e.
"ABCDE" has 5 unique letters and should be recoded with a "5".
"FAEDC" has 5 unique letters as well.

So, for my purpose the order of the sequence doesn't matter. I just want to find out how many unique letters are in a sequence and recode this 5-letter sequence into a number.

Some help would be great! (And sorry for bad English!)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `unique`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may split the strings and count `unique` in a `sapply`

```
v <- c("ABABA", "BABAB", "ABCDE", "FAEDC")
sapply(strsplit(v, ""), function(x) length(unique(x)))
# [1] 2 2 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a built-in function, but you may want to try:

```
count_unique_letters <- function(word) {
    word_length <- nchar(word)
    letters <- character(word_length)
    for(i in 1:word_length) {
        letters[i] <- substr(word, i, i)
    }
    return(length(unique(letters)))
}
```

Comment: No need to `loop` just `length` and `unique` will do

Comment: You are right! And indeed @jay.sf gave an adequate solution. However, I think this version is easier to read for an "R newbie"